# How to pause a thread within another thread in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm running multiple threads in my program and I want when a method inside a thread is called, all the other threads get paused and when that method is done, all the other threads get resumed.

I tried to use a `volatile boolean` field in my threads and make it `true` when necessary, in other threads it gets checked every time in a `while` loop. So if it is `true` I call `this.wait()` and when it's finished I make that pause `boolean` false and call `notify()` in my another thread. But it doesn't work.

Threads that I want to get paused:

```java
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.RandomAccessFile;

public class Worker extends Thread {
    RandomAccessFile file;
    long start;
    long interval;
    long end;
    long cursor;
    SourceProvider sp;
    volatile MultiThreadCopier copier;
    boolean isDone = false;
    volatile boolean paused = false;

    public Worker(String dest, long start, long interval, SourceProvider sp, MultiThreadCopier copier) {
        try {
            file = new RandomAccessFile(dest, "rws");
            file.setLength(sp.size());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        this.start = start;
        this.interval = interval;
        this.end = start + interval - 1;
        this.cursor = start;
        this.sp = sp;
        this.copier = copier;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        write();
        while (isDone) {
            Pair<Worker, Long> busiestWorkerPair = copier.busiestWorker();
            Worker busiestWorker = busiestWorkerPair.getKey();
            if (busiestWorker == null) {
                break;
            }
            long workRemaining = busiestWorkerPair.getValue();
            this.end = busiestWorker.end;
            this.start = busiestWorker.end - workRemaining / 2 + 1;
            busiestWorker.end = this.start - 1;
            isDone = false;
            busiestWorker.paused = false;
            synchronized (busiestWorker) {
                busiestWorker.notify();
            }
            write();
        }
        try {
            file.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void write() {
        SourceReader sr = sp.connect(start);
        cursor = start;
        try {
            file.seek(cursor);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        while (cursor <= end) {
            while (paused) {
                System.out.println(getName() + " paused");
                try {
                    synchronized (this) {
                        wait();
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            try {
                file.write(sr.read());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            cursor++;
        }
        isDone = true;
    }
}
```

The thread that pauses them with `busiestWorker()` method:

```java
public class MultiThreadCopier {
    public static final long SAFE_MARGIN = 6;
    Worker[] workers;

    public MultiThreadCopier(SourceProvider sourceProvider, String dest, int workerCount) {
        workers = new Worker[workerCount];
        long interval = sourceProvider.size() / workerCount;
        for (int i = 0; i < workerCount; i++) {
            long start = i * interval;
            workers[i] = new Worker(dest, start, interval + ((i + 1 == workerCount) ? sourceProvider.size() % workerCount : 0), sourceProvider, this);
        }
    }

    public void start() {
        for (Worker worker : workers) {
            worker.start();
        }
    }


    public Pair<Worker, Long> busiestWorker() {
        long mostWorkRemaining = 0;
        Worker busiestWorker = null;
        for (Worker worker : workers) {
            if (worker.isDone)
                continue;
            long remainingWork = worker.end - worker.cursor + 1;
            if (remainingWork < SAFE_MARGIN)
                continue;
            if (remainingWork <= mostWorkRemaining)
                continue;
            mostWorkRemaining = remainingWork;
            busiestWorker = worker;
        }
        if (busiestWorker == null)
            return new Pair<>(null, 0L);
        busiestWorker.paused = true;
        return new Pair<>(busiestWorker, mostWorkRemaining);
    }
}
```

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: Yes, show your code, and preferably as a [mre]. Also, do check out the [ask] and [help] links.

Comment: This sounds really brittle. I would suggest rethinking your design to use `ReentrantLock`, `CyclicBarrier`, `Semaphore`, or even `BlockingQueue` and pass immutable objects between the threads instead of sharing data. Checking a volatile variable in a loop is called "busy-waiting" and it can be a performance problem. If you do need to do it, at least call `Thread.onSpinWait()` in the loop.

Comment: Actually I can't use `java.util.concurrent` package.

Comment: Ah, one of those assignments. I see.

Comment: But how do I use a `Semaphore` here?

Comment: If this is schoolwork, say so. And state your constraints up front, don’t make us guess. Read the Help section of this site before posting here.